# keras data generator for multi task learning with non image data format

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I am working on a multi-task semantic segmentation problem with three decoders and thus, I need to feed three inputs and have three outputs. Furthermore, my datasets are not image formats(.jpg, ...) but they are .mat and .npy formats. My labels are having three values of 0,1,2 (maps with the same shape as my grayscale images). With these two in mind, I am trying to load the dataset using keras generators as my dataset is very large. Below is what I have tried based on keras documentation for generators, but to my knowledge, the documentation assumes the data as images and single task network. How can I adjust my code so that I can generators for multiple tasks and multiple data formats (non-image)?

```
def batch_generator(X_gen,Y_gen, amp_gen, phase_gen):
        while true: 
            yield(X_gen.next(),Y_gen.next(), map1_gen.next(), map2_gen.next())
```

where map1_gen and map2_gen are supposed to be generators for the other two inputs (maps).

```
train_images_dir = ''
train_masks_dir = ''
train_map1_dir = ''
train_map2_dir = ''

val_images_dir = ''
val_masks_dir = ''
val_map1_dir = ''
val_map2_dir = ''

datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_images_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_images_dir,target_size=(Img_Length,Img_Height),batch_size=batch_size,class_mode=None)
train_mask_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_masks_dir,target_size=(Img_Length,Img_Height, num_classes),batch_size=1,class_mode='categorical')
train_map1_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_map1_dir,target_size=(Img_Length,Img_Height),batch_size=batch_size,class_mode=None)
train_map2_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_map2_dir,target_size=(Img_Length,Img_Height),batch_size=batch_size ,class_mode=None)


#val augumentation.
val_images_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(val_images_dir,target_size=(Img_Length,Img_Height),batch_size=batch_size,class_mode=None)

val_masks_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(val_masks_dir,target_size=(Img_Length,Img_Height, num_classes),batch_size=1,class_mode='categorical') 
val_map1_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(val_map1_dir,target_size=(Img_Length,Img_Height),batch_size=batch_size,class_mode=None)
val_map2_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(val_map2_dir,target_size=(Img_Length,Img_Height),batch_size=batch_size,class_mode=None)

model = ...

model.fit_generator(batch_generator(train_images_generator,train_mask_generator, train_map1_generator, train_map2_generator), validation_data=batch_generator(val_images_generator,val_masks_generator, val_map1_generator, val_map2_generator),callbacks=...)
```

The outputs of each decoder is supposed to be (Img_Length,Img_Height) segmentation map with three labels 0,1,2; map1 and map2 outputs with (Img_Length,Img_Height) size of linear values respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to implement a custom generator and dismiss the ImageDataGenerator completely. E.g.

```
def batch_generator(batchsize):
    while True:
        inputs1 = []
        inputs2 = []
        inputs3 = []
        outputs1 = []
        outputs2 = []
        outputs3 = []
        for _ in batchsize:
            input1 = cv2.imread(img1) #or whatever
            inputs1.append(input1)
            inputs2.append(...)
            ...

        # you may have to convert the lists into numpy arrays

        yield([inputs1,inputs2,inputs3],[outputs1,outputs2,outputs3])
```

Basically, you directly yield a list of all your inputs and outputs, each of them being a batch.
But that means you would have to manually read them in but I think that makes sense considering you have some non-image datatypes.
You can then pass this generator to model.fit_generator (or just model.fit since tensorflow2)

```
model.fit_generator(batch_generator(batchsize))
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I will try such thing to see if it works. What outputs1, outputs2, ... are?  Are they the ground truth? My first task which is the main task has the images and the ground truth. The other two tasks are auxiliary tasks and I need to feed some maps with the same shape as the images.

Comment: [outputs1,outputs2,outputs3] are well the outputs. That could be [groundTrouthImgs,map1s,map2s] I guess in your case. Each of them being a batch so you'd have a list of groundTrouthImgs, and two list of  maps each

Comment: than makes sense. based on what I understood, I need to give the directory paths in the batch_generator and probably and index update to read the data from one index to the other index with batch size amount of data. I am wondering how I can update the indices?

Comment: Sorry i'm not quite sure I understand your question. You have to manually loop over your data and yield a batch each time. So you have to use your own indexes from the for loops you use. I'm hope that helps